# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes error

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I need some help.

Having some issues after migrating my site to a new hosting.

New staging link:

http://stage.innovativebiomedical.com/

Previous staging link that works.

http://innovative.stagingsiteinfo.com/

The error I get is:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in /home/innova71/public_html/stage/wp-content/plugins/vibe-customtypes/metaboxes/library/vibe-editor.php on line 2607

I am wondering if anyone can give me some direction as to what might be the error here with the Unserialize.

My  error log in the wordpress shows this message:

> [23-Oct-2017 15:30:13 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$v_sample_layouts' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/innova71/public_html/stage/wp-content/plugins/vibe-customtypes/metaboxes/library/vibe-editor.php on line 2607

And the code within this file its referencing is listed below (2607 is the fifth line referencing the "unserialize").

```
$v_columns = apply_filters( 'v_columns', $v_columns );
$v_sample_layouts='';
$v_sample_layouts = get_option('vibe_builder_sample_layouts');
     if(is_string($v_sample_layouts))
     $v_sample_layouts = unserialize($v_sample_layouts);

foreach( $v_columns as $v_column_key => $v_column ){
add_shortcode("v_{$v_column_key}", array($this,'new_column'));
add_shortcode("v_alt_{$v_column_key}", array($this,'new_alt_column'));
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement needs opening and closing brackets `{}`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, not necessarily : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php, the content of the "if" is just one line, brackets are optionnal.

Comment: I know @vincenth, but his isn't just one line. He has a blank in there and the line isn't indented.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I figured you knew it. I might be mistaken, but the foreach block doesn't seem to be part of the "if".

Comment: We won't know until the OP comes back and clarifies @vincenth

Answer (score 0):

Rename your "vibe-customtypes" name to "old-vibe-customtypes" from your file manager. The file root is wp-content > wp-plugin > vibe-customtypes

http://user.successfulpeoplestories.com/guest-blog-post/wordpress/how-to-fix-wordpress-blank-page-errors-and-similar-issues/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the wordpress debug at true, because this wasn't an error and just a notice, I set it to false.  Its no longer visible.

Not a solution but a quick fix.

Thanks for your help.